# how to use four different AND condition in single soql query?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, lwc, apex-sosl

I have two soql on same object but where condition is vary by single condition mentioned below, I need to combine both and make it as single soql, can someone help me how to do with below soql after where conditions?

1st one have contact.Contact_ID__c != null and 2nd one have Roles != null.I need to combine both in single soql

1st Query:

```
SELECT
    Id, 
    Roles, 
    contact.contact_Id__c, 
    Account.Id, 
    account.customer_Id__c, 
    Relationship_End_Date__c, 
    IsActive
FROM
    AccountContactRecord
WHERE
    account.customer_Id__c != null  AND  contact.Contact_ID__c != null  AND  Id  in: conList
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT
    Id, 
    Roles, 
    contact.Contact_ID__c, 
    Account.Id, 
    account.customer_Id__c, 
    Ownership__c
FROM
    AccountContactRecord
WHERE
    account.customer_Id__c != null  AND  Roles != null  AND  Id  in: conList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the conditions are identical so it's not very hard. Try to put most selective conditions first (filter by Id, by lookup, by any indexed field), good for performance.

```
where account.customer_Id__c != null and contact.Contact_ID__c != null and Id IN:conList
+
where account.customer_Id__c != null and Roles != null and Id IN:conList

becomes
WHERE Id IN:conList 
    AND Account.Customer_Id__c != null
    AND (Contact.Contact_ID__c != null OR Roles != null)
```